# Rendering multiple erb in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, rendering, erb

I have layour/application.html.erb with all required headers and nav bar. I have yield only in body section.

My dashboard.html.erb is hope page which is set of graphs. I want to write each graph in a different erb and its own javascript. So I sketched up,

dashboard.html.erb as:

```
<div> hello </div>
<%= render 'hierarchical' %>
```

and

dashboard/_hierarchical.html.erb as:

```
<head>
<%= javascript_include_tag "_hierarchical.js" %>
</head>

<div id="chart">
    test something
</div>
```

I think I need to read more about ruby which I will but need quick help on this so that I can have my sample demo app running asap. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Question was, it isnt rendering _hierarchical.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing it wrong without using :partial symbol.

This code worked

```
<div> hello </div>
<%= render :partial => 'hierarchical' %>
```